# Support ActionMenuView change popupTheme

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles

I implemented Toolbar with custom view and ActionMenuView and i can't change popup Theme for ActionMenuView.
My Toolbar Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_view"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

toolbar_view layout that contains the ActionMenuView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_home"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ldrawer_drawableSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_toggle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
            android:id="@+id/amvMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_toolbar_home"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ll_menu"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_title_padding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_font_size"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the result is:
[image]

[image]

The question is, How i can change the drop down menu background to be white?

Answer (score -1):

just make your `android:textColorPrimary`in your theme to be white

Comment: I know but i want to make popup menu background white and item text color black